# Why is the WPF TreeViewItem.Expanded "sender" passing TreeView instead of TreeViewItem?

Tags: wpf, treeview

How do I access the TreeViewItem (or rather the object) that is being expanded?  In my estimation "sender" from the event handler should be the TreeViewItem not TreeView.  I want to act on the object bound to the TreeViewItem when it is expanded.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<StackPanel>
    <TreeView x:Name="treeView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              TreeViewItem.Expanded="treeViewItem_Expanded" >
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</StackPanel>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Element root = new Element() { Name = "root" };
        Element a1 = new Element() { Name = "a1" };
        Element a2 = new Element() { Name = "a2" };
        Element b1 = new Element() { Name = "b2" };
        root.Add(a1);
        root.Add(a2);
        a2.Add(b1);
        treeView.ItemsSource = root;
     }

    private void treeViewItem_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem tvi = sender as TreeViewItem;
        tvi = e.Source as TreeViewItem;
        TreeView tv = sender as TreeView;
    }

    public interface IElement
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Element : ObservableCollection<IElement>, IElement
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `e.OriginalSource` is a TreeViewItem, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TreeViewItem.Selected` event. Selected event which bubbles up to the tree view (the TreeViewItem's themselves do not exist at design time as we are using a HierarchicalDataTemplate).

The event can be captured in XAML as so:

```
<TreeView TreeViewItem.Selected="TreeViewItemSelected" .../>
```

Then the last TreeViewItem selected can be set in the event as so:

```
private void TreeViewItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem tvi = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;

    // set the last tree view item selected variable which may be used elsewhere as there is no other way I have found to obtain the TreeViewItem container (may be null)
    this.lastSelectedTreeViewItem = tvi;

    ...
 }
```

Comment: Clicking on the expansion arrow doesn't trigger the Selected event.

Comment: I have tested your code. It doesn't display any tree view for me. Please post working code so that somebody could reproduce the issue.